# What is the efficient way to get a specific substring from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string as follows:

```
"[error=<null>,EntityID=105378032, Context=<null>]"
```

and i want to extract the `EntityID`( in this case `105378032`), but i want a generalize solution of doing it.

What is the most efficient way of doing it.

I don't want to traverse the string and get that part.

Comment: "I don't want to traverse the string and get that part.".
Then I guess, storing it in a `String` wasn't the best thing you could've done.

Comment: s.substring(8, 26)?

Comment: its a part of a big project in which they have already stored it, is there a single statement command of doing it?

Comment: @JB Nizel i want a generalize solution.

Comment: Is your `EntityID` _always_ of a fixed number of digits?

Comment: Then explain **precisely** what it should do. Ans try coming up with a solution by yourself. What should the code do? What is the **precise** format of the string?

Comment: no, its a variable and i don't know the exact number of digit.

Comment: split the string at ',' first , for 2nd index of it  then split it at '=' this will work as long as your input in the same format as you wrote above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try regex like `.*EntityID=(.*?),.*` which mean get the group of characters between `EntityID=` and the next comma `,` using `replaceAll` :

```
String str = "[error=,EntityID=105378032, Context=]";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*EntityID=(.*?),.*", "$1"));// output 105378032
```

#### regex demo

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular expressions seems to be the best way out.

This code works:

```
String str = "[error=,EntityID=105378032, Context=]";
    String[] arr = str.split("EntityID="); //splits it on the part "EntityID="
    String[] arr1 = arr[1].split(","); // splits it on the next comma in the 'right' half of your string.
    System.out.println(arr1[0]); //prints the 'left' half before the comma.
```

[Ideone link here.](https://ideone.com/vvKqhv)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method it's work like a charm

```
public static String getSubString(String mainString, String lastString, String startString) {
        String endString = "";
        int endIndex = mainString.indexOf(lastString);
        int startIndex = mainString.indexOf(startString);
        endString = mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        return endString;
    }
```

**Result:**

```
String resultStr = getSubString(yourFullString,",Context","EntityID=");
```

Happy codding.